# Can't combine two tables into one

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to combine two tables into one, but it doesn't work very well...
One Table is called Lat and the other Table is called Lng, the columns have the same name.

So, Lat Lat and Lng Lng (Table Lat, column Lat - Table Lng, column Lng)

Currently, I'm using the following piece of code (in php)

```
$query  = "INSERT INTO Combo (COMLAT, COMLNG) SELECT * FROM Lat UNION ALL SELECT * FROM Lng";
```

but it doesn't work, it only imports the values into the second column of the Combo table:

```
    +----+--------+------------+
| ID | COMLAT | COMLNG     |
+----+--------+------------+
| 50 | 1      | 52.2522863 |
| 51 | 1      | 6.20641011 |
| 53 | 1      | 6.20641011 |
| 54 | 1      | 52.2522863 |
| 56 | 1      | 6.20641011 |
| 57 | 1      | 52.2522863 |
| 59 | 1      | 6.20641011 |
| 60 | 1      | 52.2522863 |
| 62 | 1      | 52.2522863 |
| 63 | 1      | 6.20641011 |
| 65 | 1      | 52.2522863 |
| 66 | 1      | 6.20641011 |
| 68 | 1      | 52.2522863 |
| 69 | 1      | 6.20641011 |
+----+--------+------------+
```

I thought that

```
(COMLAT, COMLNG)
```

means that you select COMLAT and COMLNG columns?
Or did I forget/miss something?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Combo (COMLAT, COMLNG) 
SELECT A.* FROM Lat A 
UNION ALL 
SELECT B.* FROM Lng B
```

Comment: Hello,
This unformutaly didnt work, even when i tried in PMA in the SQL Tab.
It gives me the same ouput as before.
But when i try this in the php file, it doesnt work at all...
What does the A and B mean anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Yay, got it to work.
it was:

```
INSERT INTO Combo (COMLAT, COMLNG)
SELECT Lat, Lng FROM Lat, Lng
```

not really sure why it worked, but i really thought that i needed UNION

Thanks anyway!

Comment: You can accept your own answer to close the question!